# Is there a way to update Dropbox files through api?

Tags: flutter, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have configured upload and download APIs, but I am unable to find the update API in the documentation.

When I re-use the upload API, it doesn't rewrite the file and gives a 409 error response.

Does Dropbox have any update API, or is it like a file cannot be updated at all?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Is-there-any-way-to-update-a-File-using-API-s-or-Java-SDK/m-p/754976/highlight/true#M33055 ]